# Celery queues and Redis queues

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I was looking at some tutorials for setting up Redis (message broker) + Celery for Django and I'm a little confused about how the queues work. The tutorial I followed was https://hackernoon.com/asynchronous-tasks-with-celery-redis-in-django-3e00d3735686

1. Does redis have an inbuilt queue as the message broker? Or is the queue a part of celery?
2. Which queue is the task pushed onto? The redis queue or the celery queue?

[In this diagram it looks like redis and celery have their own queues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUfk7.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Celery does not have its own queue (at least not in that architecture). Redis will hold all the tasks in the queue, and then a celery worker node will consume the task from the Redis queue.

Comment: The arch. from the tutorial or diagram?

Comment: Both. They both describe the same process. Celery is not supposed to be stateful, it just does something and then moves onto the next task.

Comment: Here's a minimum working example if it helps: https://github.com/stuart23/django-kubernetes-demo/tree/celery